# How to reproduce this algorithm?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, image-processing

I am trying to reproduce one of the algorithms presented in the following paper:
*[Rapid Assessment of Annual Deforestation in the Brazilian Amazon Using MODIS Data](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/EI139.1)*

The authors provide five different algorithms to identify new deforestation using satellite imagery. The first algorithm is described as follows:

> **Two-date image differencing**: The difference in the reflectance,
>   vegetation index, or other input data values between images from 2002
>   and 2001 was classified using mean plus 0.5, 1, or 2 standard
>   deviations of the mean difference. Values that exceeded this threshold
>   were classified as deforestation.

I already have the 2002 and 2001 images, which consist in the Vegetation Continous Fields MODIS product. This products has values that represent the percent of tree coverage, so the values range from 0 to 100 (100 being a pixel with complete tree coverage).

Suppose I had the following data (n = 10):

```
2000    2001    Diff
  66      45      21
  98      80      18
  90      90       0
  86      67      19
  89      80       9
  75      45      30
  82      55      27
  68      64       4
  75      70       5
  84      40      44
```

I am confused about how to reproduce this method in order to calculate the threshold.

> mean plus 0.5, 1, or 2 standard deviations of the mean difference

What is the mean in this case? Mean of 2001, 2000, both years combined or the mean difference? And furthermore, how should I calculate the standard deviation of the mean difference? Should I use this equation?

[image]

where s(V) is the standard deviation of the `diff` values.

Taking a look at the values, the only way that makes sense to calculate this threshold is using the mean difference. Otherwise the threshold would be to high to account for deforestation identification.

Intepreting mean as the mean difference with the former data, the threshold would be:

[image]

[image]

which seems like a reasonable value. However, I find the algorithm's description a little bit ambiguous and am not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Honestly I'm not certain anyone here can answer that question. I can tell you what I would have done -- but it seems like the authors haven't actually fully specified their procedure.

Comment: Yeah, this question is probably better suited for GIS Stack Exchange but I didn't see the option to vote for migrating it there. The only options were SO and Math Stack Exchange.